# JavaFx Combobox lazy loading images

Tags: java, combobox, javafx

I am using the JavaFX Combobox for the first time... and I have over 2000 icons in the combobox (they can be filtered via AutoCompleteComboBoxListener that I found from StackOverflow).

I am planning to use the ExecutorService to fetch the images from a zip-file.

Now, the problem is that how can I figure out the currently visible items in the Combobox?

I am setting a custom ListCellFactory for the ComboBox, and I have a custom ListCell class, that also displays the icon. Can I somehow check from within the ListCell object whether the item "is showing" ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to check that?

Comment: Like I said there can be possibly 2000 icons in the ComboBox's popup at once, and my plan was to load and display the ones that are visible in the viewport of the ComboBox's popup - as the user scrolls the popups's scrollpane.

Comment: The cell mechanism takes care of that (more or less). Added an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just note first that if you are loading the images from individual files instead of from a zip file, there is a mechanism that avoids having to work directly with any kind of threading at all:

```
ComboBox<MyDataType> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
comboBox.setCellFactory(listView -> new ListCell<MyDataType>() {

    private ImageView imageView = new ImageView();

    @Override
    public void updateItem(MyDataType item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            String imageURL = item.getImageURL();
            Image image = new Image(imageURL, true); // true means load in background
            imageView.setImage(image);
            setGraphic(imageView);
        }
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, if you're loading from a zip file, I don't think you can use this, so you'll need to create your own background tasks. You need to just be a little careful to make sure that you don't use an image loaded in the background if the item in the cell changes during the loading process (which is pretty likely if the user scrolls a lot).

(Update note: I changed this to listen for changes in the `itemProperty()` of the cell, instead of using the `updateItem(...)` method. The `updateItem(...)` method can be called more frequently than when the actual item displayed by the cell changes, so this approach avoids unnecessary "reloading" of images.)

Something like:

```
ExecutorService exec = ... ;
ComboBox<MyDataType> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
comboBox.setCellFactory(listView -> {

    ListCell<MyDataType> cell = new ListCell<MyDataType>() ;

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
    ObjectProperty<Task<Image>> loadingTask = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    cell.emptyProperty().addListener((obs, wasEmpty, isNotEmpty) -> {
        if (isNowEmpty) {
            cell.setGraphic(null);
            cell.setText(null);
        } else {
            cell.setGraphic(imageView);
        }
    });

    cell.itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldItem, newItem) ->  {
        if (loadingTask.get() != null && 
            loadingTask.get().getState() != Worker.State.SUCCEEDED &&
            loadingTask.get().getState() != Worker.State.FAILED) {

            loadingTask.get().cancel();
        }
        loadingTask.set(null) ;
        if (newItem != null) {
            Task<Image> task = new Task<Image>() {
                @Override
                public Image call() throws Exception {
                    Image image = ... ; // retrieve image for item
                    return image ;
                }
            };
            loadingTask.set(task);
            task.setOnSucceeded(event -> imageView.setImage(task.getValue()));
            exec.submit(task);

            cell.setText(...); // some text from item...
        }
    }); 

    return cell ;
});
```

Some thoughts on performance here:

First, the "virtualized" mechanism of the `ComboBox` means that only a small number of these cells will ever be created, so you don't need to worry that you're immediately starting thousands of threads loading images, or indeed that you will ever have thousands of images in memory.

When the user scrolls through the list, the `itemProperty(...)` may change quite frequently as the cells are reused for new items. It's important to make sure you don't use images from threads that are started but don't finish before the item changes again; that's the purpose of canceling an existing task at the beginning of the item change listener. Canceling the task will prevent the `onSucceeded` handler from being invoked. However, you will still have those threads running, so if possible the implementation of your `call()` method should check the `isCancelled()` flag and abort as quickly as possible if it returns true. This might be tricky to implement: I would experiment and see how it works with a simple implementation first.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comprehensive answer. I had no idea Image could do background loading out-of-box. And, the javadoc of Image states that it searches from the classpath too, and my zip-file is bundled with my app, so I had no problems adding it to the classpath... I got everything working just fine.

Comment: How would you go about caching images?
I have been successfully using your method, however, sometimes large images take a long time to load in, and for those items, the previous image is shown. Caching them would alleviate this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Even if your list has 2000 items javafx will only create listcell objects for the visible cells (plus one or two more for half visible cells) so there's not really a lot TODO for you to load Images lazy - just load them when updateItem is called - and maybe cache already loaded Images in a lifo Cache so that not all of them stay in memory

Comment: Scrolling could be pretty ugly if you're extracting an image from a zip file on demand on the FX Application Thread, though, no?

Answer (score 0):

Current visible item implies the current selected item on combobox. You can get the selected item using

```
comboboxname.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
```

Comment: Well, I meant the currently visible items in the popup of the Combobox.

Comment: what popup? you mean autocomplete popup?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear.. I mean the popup when you click the down arrow button on the combobox, and by visible items I mean the items that are currently showing in the ScrollPane of the popup.

Comment: scrollpane size depends. Are you sure what you trying to do is the best way to approach it?

Comment: No I am not. :) I'm all open for ideas, I've never really implemented such a thing before.